# Flutter Agora PlatformException(7, not initialized, null, null)

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am developing a voice call application using Flutter Agora SDK. So far, I have been able to comfortably perform voice calls without any errors. But today, while testing it on my real device, it gives an error even though I haven't made any changes to the initializing process. Even strangely, it works without any error on the emulator, but only on the real device gives error.

```
Future<void> initAgora() async {
    await [Permission.microphone].request();
    try {
      engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(RtcEngineContext(APP_ID));

      await engine.enableAudio();
      await engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.Communication);

      engine.setEventHandler(
        RtcEngineEventHandler(
          activeSpeaker: (i) {
            log("Active Speaker: $i");
          },
          microphoneEnabled: (enable) {
            log("Microphone: " + enable.toString());
            callingController.microphoneState.value = enable;
          },
          warning: (warningCode) {
            print(warningCode.toString());
          },
          rtcStats: (stats) {
            log("User Count: ${stats.userCount}");
          },
          connectionStateChanged: (state, reason) {
            log("Connection Changed : ${state.toString()}, ${reason.toString()}");
          },
          joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
            log('joinChannelSuccess $channel $uid');
          },
          userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
            log('userJoined $uid');
          },
          userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
            log('userOffline $uid');
            callingController.finishCall(uid, "user_left");
          },
          error: (error) {
            log("ERROR: $error", name: "AGORA");
          },
        ),
      );

      if (callingController.isCallerMe) {
        await joinChannel();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      failureSnackbar(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What real device are you using? When is this exception thrown?

Comment: My real device is Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro. `await engine.setChannelProfile()` line when working thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you shared occurs when you try calling a method before the SDK has been initialised properly. Can you please check your RtcEngine config. Also, if you have enabled tokens in your project please make sure that you pass it to the config.